# Remove file name from file in bash

Tags: bash, file

I need to **remove names from output of file**.

I am using

```
file $variable -N
```

then i use **sed**

but it didn't work.

Output of **file** is

```
./: directory
./whatever: data
./testfile: ASCII text
```

and I expect output from **sed**

```
directory
data
ASCII text
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any external command. Use `-b` option in `file` command.

```
file -b file
```

> From `man file`:
>
> ```
> -b, --brief
>       Do not prepend filenames to output lines (brief mode).
> ```

Comment: Also worth adding `-b` is not defined by `POSIX` here, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html BUT only on `FreeBSD` systems, https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=file&sektion=1

Comment: Thanks a lot! But somehow it do not recognize files with space in them

Comment: @Brky, Use quotes : `file "$variable"`

Comment: @sat
dir=$(find $variable) #variable is path to directory;
var=$(file "$dir" -b)

Comment: @Brky, Are you sure that `$dir` is having valid path of the filename ? Check `$dir` value and try `ls "$dir"`.

Comment: @sat $dir is output of find $variable
./: directory
./whatever: data
./testfile: ASCII text